# Tcl fileevent hangs on 64 bit version of Tcl

Tags: c++, linux, tcl, 64-bit, x11

I am using 64 bit 8.4.3 Tcl Non-Threaded on Linux and I am facing a weird behavior.

My C++ application has a timer that executes some Xt handlers using `XtAppProcessEvent`. One of the handlers calls `Tcl_DoOneEvent`.

I have a Tcl script that opens an empty pipe and attaches a fileevent to the opened channel.

```
set jobId [open "| "]
fileevent $jobId readable
```

This gets done multiple times. After some times when the channel name is `file35` the tool hangs. Using a debug version of the Tcl library. It shows that the readyMasks[0] is always 0 after executing the following part:

```
// tclUnixNotfy.c:772
numFound = select(tsdPtr->numFdBits,
    (SELECT_MASK *) &tsdPtr->readyMasks[0],
    (SELECT_MASK *) &tsdPtr->readyMasks[MASK_SIZE],
    (SELECT_MASK *) &tsdPtr->readyMasks[2*MASK_SIZE], timeoutPtr);
```

The input check masks are 72 (1001000).

---

Here is the weird part:

When I reach the part where the tools hangs, if I open a new shell tab the tool no longer hangs and continues execution as expected. The `readyMasks` become 72 when a new shell tab gets opened.

The tool operated normally when it was 32 bit. I can't relate what's happening to being 64 bit.

I have tried this on redhat 5, 6 and 7 and there was no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Can you try with 8.6.9? 8.6.3 is a rather old point release now.

Comment: Also, _opening an empty pipe?!_ What on earth is that supposed to do? I didn't know it ever worked… but it isn't supposed to. I get a “`illegal use of | or |& in command`” when I try it.

Comment: @DonalFellows I tried upgrading to `8.6.6` but everything broke. The application is huge and such upgrade isn't so simple.
It does work I am 100% my application makes use of it a lot. As for the reason why it is used, it is used to schedule an event to be processed on the next `Tcl_DoOneEvent`. This way some `Xt` events gets executed to keep the UI responsive.

Comment: I am aware of recent changes to channels in 8.6.x where `poll` is used instead of `select`. I am not able to do that huge upgrade though while my tool is heavily dependent on Tcl.

Comment: The OP says 8.4.3, not 8.6.3 (but this seems to have changed)?

Comment: @mrcalvin My question is about 8.4.3 not 8.6.3. I was only explaining that I have tried updating the Tcl version and I couldn't.

Comment: Well, Donal's comments related to 8.6.3 (see above). 8.4 is another beast, beyond its end-of-life. Aside, as Donal states, `open "|"` is simply disallowed, and always used to be: in my `8.4.18`, it also shouts:  `illegal use of | or |& in command`

Comment: Found [the commit where this changed](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/info/47d7a23bdf3cdc08) and [its associated ticket](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/tktview/768659), which dates from back in 2006 and whose fix was part of 8.4.13.

Comment: That also means it is in all non-alpha releases of 8.5.

Comment: Yes I just tested another tool I have that uses `8.6.6` and got `illegal use of | or |& in command`.

Comment: I have found a solution to my issue please check my answer below if you're interested. It was not related at all to the empty `open` pipe but was a classic 64 bit memory issue when manipulating `long` masks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured out the issue.

The issue is basically due to shifting in an `integer` instead of a `long`. This in Tcl is done in `tclUnixChan.c` while calculating the index and bit to that needs to be modified in `tsdPtr->checkMasks`:

```
index = fd/(NBBY*sizeof(fd_mask)); 
bit = 1 << (fd%(NBBY*sizeof(fd_mask)));
```

The bit line needs to be `1L <<` instead of `1 <<`. `fd_mask` itself is a `long` and is defined in `sys/types.h`. This was only a part of the problem.

`sys/types.h` also has definitions of macros that should be used when setting or clearing bits in fd_masks (`FD_CLR`, `FD_SET`, `FD_ISSET`, `FD_ZERO`).

This issue was fixed partially in version `8.4.9` and was fully fixed in version `8.4.20`.

The fix was done by using the macros defined in `types.h` instead of manually manipulating the `fd_mask` bits.

The partial fix introduced in version `8.4.9` was in `tclUnixNotfy.c`:

1. struct `SelectMasks` was created which uses `fd_set` type that is defined in `types.h`
2. ThreadSpecificData `checkMasks` and `readyMasks` fields changed from a `fd_mask` arrays to be `SelectMasks`
3. `index` and `bit` variables used in `Tcl_CreateFileHandler`, `Tcl_DeleteFileHandler`, `Tcl_WaitForEvent`, `NotifierThreadProc` to deal with the masks were removed and `FD_CLR`, `FD_SET`, `FD_ISSET`, `FD_ZERO` were used instead.
4. `Tcl_WaitForEvent` assigns `readyMasks` to `checkMasks` instead of using `memcpy` before calling `select`
5. Casting the `readyMasks` to `SELECT_MASK *` when calling select is now removed and `&` operator is now used on the `SelectMasks` struct elements of type `fd_set` directly.

The other part of the fix introduced in version `8.4.20` was in `tclUnixChan.c`:

1. `index` and `bit` variables used in `TclUnixWaitForFile` to deal with the masks were removed and `FD_CLR`, `FD_SET`, `FD_ISSET`, `FD_ZERO` were used instead.
2. `fd_set` type was used instead of creating `fd_mask` arrays in `TclUnixWaitForFile`.
3. Casting masks to `SELECT_MASK *` when calling select is now removed and `&` operator is now used on the created `fd_set` variables directly.

I have patched my current version of `8.4.3` guided by the changes done in `8.4.9` and `8.4.20` because I don't have the flexibility of upgrading the whole `Tcl` version.

---

My theory on why opening a new shell window got the tool to work:

Due to that memory corruption caused by shifting in a container of the wrong size and using `memcpy` with a weird length `3*MASK_SIZE`, the `fd` I ended up pointing to are window management related hence why opening a new shell got select to return non zero value due to having data on those wrong `fd` channels I am pointing to.

What led me to that theory was the `strace` output as well as `lsof` output:

`strace` output while hanging had the following part being repeated:

```
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 2, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvfrom(4, 0x80e21f4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(4, 0x80e21f4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 2, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvfrom(6, 0x8380d64, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(36, [3 6], [], [], {0, 0})       = 0 (Timeout)
recvfrom(6, 0x8380d64, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(6, 0x8380d64, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(36, [3 6], [], [], {0, 0})       = 0 (Timeout)
recvfrom(6, 0x8380d64, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 2, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {0x4c3cd70, [CHLD], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x37eec0f790}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
```

`strace` output when I opened a new shell tab changed to:

```
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(4, "X\1\366\371\264\300\7=\3\0\22\0\10\377\0\0\26\1\26\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096, 0, NULL, NULL) = 256
recvfrom(4, 0x80e21f4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(4, 0x80e21f4, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 2, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvfrom(6, "X\1\321/\264\300\7=\3\0\22\0\10\377\0\0\26\1\26\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096, 0, NULL, NULL) = 256
recvfrom(6, 0x8380d64, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(36, [3 6], [], [], {0, 0})       = 1 (in [3], left {0, 0})
recvfrom(6, 0x8380d64, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
read(35, "", 4096)                      = 0
close(35)                               = 0
```

`lsof` output shows the following for channel `4` and `6`:

```
myexec 13626 aymansalah    4u  IPv4 1607796326       0t0        TCP rhe6x64:38787->nx-svr:7016 (ESTABLISHED)
myexec 13626 aymansalah    6u  IPv4 1607837231       0t0        TCP rhe6x64:38788->nx-svr:7016 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Channels `4` and `6` are channels connecting my machine to the NX server.

---

References:

- [Old thread mentioning the issue](http://tcl.2662.n7.nabble.com/tcl-Bugs-1602208-select-on-wrong-fd-td11494.html)
- [Issue that was fixed in 8.4.9](https://sourceforge.net/p/tcl/bugs/2974/)
- [Issue that was fixed in 8.4.20](https://sourceforge.net/p/tcl/bugs/5001/)
- [sys/types.h](https://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/Net2/newsrc/sys/types.h.html)